# C# - Only run immediate function with threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here's what I have. When my application starts up, it creates a thread and runs my `startListening()` function. But what it seems to do, is run any other functions called within `startListening` under the same thread. Is there a way I can make it so that ONLY the things immediately inside of `startListening` are ran with that thread, and not the functions called from within that?

It would just make it a lot easier for me when referencing controls and things that aren't within that thread so I don't have to Invoke each time.

EDIT: Maybe this isn't the right thing to be asking. I know I had to `Invoke` with setting textboxes, but now I need to make a timer enabled. Its not throwing any exceptions when I try to enable it, but rather just not "ticking". Here's my code:

```
    private void beginListenerThread()
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(startListening);
        thread1.Start();
    }

    private void startListening()
    {
        timer1.enabled = true;
    }
```

But it doesn't tick.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could post some code it might help see what the problem is. But my initial thought is that it might be callbacks you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, after re-reading your question, you're still going to need invokes with callbacks.

Comment: @ConorGallagher I updated the OP with my actual problem, could you please take a look? Thanks :)

Comment: Please show declaration and initialization of timer1. As an aside: you really don't need a thread for something as simple as this. I hope your actual code does more work in the thread.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten My thread does MUCH more, thats just simplified. Not sure what you mean by declaration and initialization, its a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: Then you need this.Invoke(delegate { timer1.Start(); }); as minitech pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the kind of trouble you'll run into when you use a class that is not thread-safe on a thread.  The Winforms Timer class generates Tick events from a little hidden helper window, a window that receives WM_TIMER messages generated by the Windows SetTimer() api function and turns them into Tick event calls.  That window is created when you enable the timer.

What goes wrong here is that this window gets created on the wrong thread.  It needs a message pump to dispatch the WM_TIMER notifications, that thread doesn't have one.  It could have one by calling Application.Run() but you don't want to go there.

Follow the advice given in the MSDN Library article's Remarks section:

> The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace.

Or the System.Threading.Timer class, a timer class that's a bit less cranky.

Comment: Okay I think I understand you. So you're saying I should be creating the timer at runtime? Thanks :)

Comment: No, the Remarks section is telling you to use a different Timer class.  Are you sure you're ready to tackle threading yet?  Always difficult to get right.  Best to leave on the shelf for a while until you get some more experience.

Comment: Yeah I need to, I'm using a `TcpListener` and without threading everything just freezes up. Could you explain more how to use the different timer class? All I've done so far is added into my form a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` :/

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not possible automatically. If you are able to modify the method that should be called on another thread, change the calls to other methods so that they're run on the originating thread. If you're using Windows Forms, use `this.Invoke` or `this.BeginInvoke`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do this when I need to set textboxes or something, but Timers seem to be different. I updated the OP, mind taking a look? :)

Comment: @DannyF247: Is is a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`? You still need to use `Invoke`, something like `this.Invoke(delegate { timer1.Start(); });`

Comment: @DannyF247: Sorry, I meant `this.Invoke`, not `timer1.Invoke`.